# iOS (iPad) PWA + SyncManager API

Tags: web-applications, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, offline-caching, background-sync

It seems that SyncManager API not compatible with browsers on iOS14.4 (iPad)
https://caniuse.com/?search=syncmanager

May I have your advice if there is any alternative API or web development solution to handle background sync process with iOS14.4 (iPad)?

Many thanks!

Best regards,
Nicky.